# Replacing screen and hinges in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, laptop-display

Aesthetics aside, is it possible to replace a laptop screen with one from a different laptop (make, model, size, etc).

Basically, I have a hp DM1z (11.6inch) with a cracked screen and an old 15inch gateway from 2008, both gathering dust.

How would I get started?

Answer (score 1):

Screens are not universal.  There are physical differences in where and how the connecting cables are routed, what connectors are used, the electronics and interfacing, etc.  Almost anything can be done if you have enough time, talent, and money.  However, the chances are low that the two screens are interchangeable in the sense that all you need to figure out is how to physically attach the replacement screen and then plug in its cables.

As far as your two laptops, a better solution would be to buy a direct replacement screen if it is worth repairing the HP or put that money toward a new laptop.  Stick a lightweight Linux on the Gateway and give it new life.  There are many that will run well on limited resources in an old machine.  Some are small and load entirely into memory (applications and all), and can knock your socks off with lightning performance on a tired old machine you thought was worthless.

This is not a direct answer to your question of how do I go about swapping the screens.  That is unlikely to be practical, so this is an alternate approach.

Comment: The gateway also has a faulty motherboard and is prone to overheating, in addition to being way underpowered...  The point is thst neither are worth the cost of fixing, but I have the time and don't mind fiddling. You're saying that assuming the connections are the same it's a basic switch - and if they're not? Is it undo able or just impractical?

Comment: If you are going to trash them anyway, there is nothing to lose by looking.  However, the odds that one will be plug and play on the other are extremely low.  Even if the cabling happens to be close enough and the connectors are the same type, there may be differences in the controls (like brightness/contrast), and in the interfacing.  Unless you have the right tools, (and wiring diagrams), it would be very difficult to even replace the connectors.  If everything physically matches, try it.  If the connections are different, it will be impractical and uneconomical to modify.

Answer (score 0):

There are vendors who sell replacement screens for laptops - you would need to check if the screen size you need is sold.

It's not too difficult - armed with a size 0 cross head screwdriver to remove the fascia covering the screen - to replace the screen. See [this article](http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/laptops/how-to-replace-a-broken-laptop-screen-658906) for details of how to replace.

Comment: i think what @suspectus is suggesting is more doable than trying to swap a screen from a different vendor. You can attempt to use to existing parts, but you have to do the research to do see if the connectors and parts are compatible. I think its just better to go the replacement route. I know this is opinion, but your question is fraught with risk that replacing minimizes.

Comment: Risk is of little concern - I'm not spending the money so it's either try my hand at the switch or leave them in the wasteland of broken electronics.